# How to pass AJAX results back to requester page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have seen a few snippets attempting to explain how this is done however I am struggling to integrate the code.  As you will see from my code and previous questions I am new to AJAX but finding it thoroughly rewarding.

Basically, I am in the process of creating a small ticketing system for internal job management and problem tracking.

So far I have a drop down form where you select the user and using AJAX the users assets are returned from MySQL.  There is then a tick box on the subject heading.  (This will be moving to the asset as realised that some users may have multiple assets.)

What I need to understand is how to pass back to the original form what assets are selected within the AJAX result so that the asset is recording when the ticket is submitted.

All the code below is not currently sanitised and needs a good clean!

This is the AJAX code and form from the original page:

```
<h3>Assign User</h3> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","./includes/submit-ticket-ajax-1.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<select style="width:217px; height:20px !important;" name="company_staff_select" onchange="showUser(this.value)">

            <option value=""></option>';

      $o = "SELECT * FROM company_staff WHERE company_id = " . $company_id . " ORDER BY id DESC";
    $rs = mysql_query($o);
    $nr = mysql_num_rows($rs);
    for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++) {
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$staff_id = $r['id'];

            echo '<option id="person" name="person" value="' . $staff_id . '">' . $r['firstname'] . ' ' . $r['lastname'] . '</option>';
}

echo '

</select>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

This is the code of the page called by AJAX:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];



$sql="SELECT * FROM company_staff WHERE id = '$q'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


$users_computer = $row['computer_id'];
$users_sim = $row['sim_id'];
$users_mobile = $row['mobile_id'];




$sql2="SELECT * FROM company_computers WHERE `id` = '$users_computer'";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);




$sql3="SELECT * FROM company_sims WHERE id = '$users_sim'";

$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);

$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);




$sql4="SELECT * FROM company_mobiles WHERE id = '$users_mobile'";

$result4 = mysql_query($sql4);

$row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);




echo '<br /><table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Email<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="' . $row['email'] . '"  /></th>
<th>Computer Name<input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="' . $row2['id'] . '"  /></th>
<th>Company Phone Number<input type="checkbox" name="sim" value="' . $row3['id'] . '"  /></th>
<th>Company Mobile<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="' . $row['id'] . '"  /></th>
</tr>';

  echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row2['computer_name'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row3['phone_number'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row4['make'] . ' ' . $row4['model'] . '</td>

    </tr>


<tr>
<b>Please select the device this ticket is related to if any.</b>
</tr>


        ';




echo '</table>';

?>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and the more broken down the greater the appreciation!

Kind Regards,

n00bstacker

Comment: are you open to using a JavaScript library for this? it could be done much more easier using a library like jquery, mootools or dojo.

Comment: what error handling, debugging are you trying?  Are you logging anything to trace the execution of your code?

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu - thanks - at the minute I am just adding a tool onto an already existing platform and did not want to use separate PHP steps and wanted to try and learn a bit about AJAX.  The long term plan is to re engineer the entire platform into separate subject matter code bases and use an apache project (name slips my mind) to talk between them.  So open to anything that is not re-engineering really as that's already being done by someone much more talented than myself.  I just saw an excuse to try and advance my skills a little.

Comment: @thescientist - I'm new to the AJAX scene so not sure on best practices - currently I am using HttpFox to view what the browser is seeing.  From by brief knowledge I guess I am expecting to see a response back in the form of POST Data but currently getting nothing back.  Other than that just standard PHP/MySQL logging.

Comment: learn to use console.log so you can see what your JS is doing too.  Also, you can manually hit the php page in your browser and pass the query string via GET for the time being, till you can be absolutely sure you can see the output in your browser first.  then switch it over to POST and try it from the JS, using logging and debugging to trace it out.

Comment: and the best practices of debugging/logging apply to programming of all languages.  Learning how to debug should be the first task/priority when learning to develop in any language.  Never assume what the code is doing.  Find out for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easier using jQuery.
Just include the jQuery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#idOfYourSelectBox').change(function(){
       var val = $(this).val();

       //post submits data via post
       $.post("./includes/submit-ticket-ajax-1.php", {"id" : val}, function(data){
          $('#txtHint').html(data); //the same as innerHTML in javascript
       });
       //you can also pass more data by adding items in the map:
       //{"id" : val, "name" : val2}
       //or simply serialize the form if you're submitting a form via ajax, this way you won't need to get the individual values for each field
    });
</script>
```

Data is submitted to `submit-ticket-ajax-1.php` via `POST`. Which is the same as that of when submitting forms:

```
<form method="post">
```

The only difference is that its doing it without full page refresh.

And since you submitted the data via `POST` you will also have to access it using  `$_POST` in PHP just like how you get the data from normal html forms.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Then you can just use `$id` in your query. Of course you will have to verify if its valid, and make sure that it's sanitized to prevent things like sql injection.

I also noticed that you're still using the original `mysql api` for php. If you have read in the official php documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php
it isn't recommended anymore. You can use `PDO` or `MySQLi` to take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) which prevents sql injection.

Some advice (I'm not really an expert so its always wise to verify what you're learning by doing a quick google search):

PHP is a templating language so instead of echoing html out, only echo out values inside html:

```
<td><?php echo  $row['firstname']; ?></td>
```

And not:

```
echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>
```

**Updates:**

In your original code you have this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","./includes/submit-ticket-ajax-1.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

When you convert it to jquery code it will look like this:

```
$.get("./includes/submit-ticket-ajax-1.php", {'q' : str});
```

Then in your `submit-ticket-ajax-1.php` file you are accessing the value that was passed via ajax and using it on your query:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
$sql="SELECT * FROM company_staff WHERE id = '$q'";
```

And I somehow got lost because there were also a bunch of queries after that. But I assume that you're making use of the results of that query to generate html which is this one:

```
echo '<br /><table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Email<input type="checkbox" name="email" value="' . $row['email'] . '"  /></th>
<th>Computer Name<input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="' . $row2['id'] . '"  /></th>
<th>Company Phone Number<input type="checkbox" name="sim" value="' . $row3['id'] . '"  /></th>
<th>Company Mobile<input type="checkbox" name="mobile" value="' . $row['id'] . '"  /></th>
</tr>';
```

You're saying that you want to pass in data from `submit-ticket-ajax-1.php` file to the page where you are originally calling ajax right?
That's why you don't need the html with the table and forms inside of it.
What you need is to encode the results of the query into json so that it can be parsed by javascript later on the client side. 
And since you have multiple results sets you might want to store them all in an array like this and then use `json_encode` to convert it to json format.

```
$data = array("row" => $row, "row2" => $row2);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Going back to the client side code. You now have to call `JSON.parse` to convert the json string to a javascript object so that it can be manipulated using javascript:

```
   $.post("./includes/submit-ticket-ajax-1.php", {"id" : val}, function(data){
      var json_data = JSON.parse(data); //convert to object
      //accessing the data that was passed
      var email = json_data['row']['email'];
      var row2_id = json_data['row2']['id'];


   });
```

Now that you have the data, you can just suppply the values to the forms using javascript. I assume that you have a hidden container somewhere and the form that you want to supply values is inside that container:

```
<div style="display:none;">
```

In which case all you have to do is assign the data fetched via ajax into those forms like:

```
$('#email').val(email);
```

But of course you can also do what you were originally doing by just generating the html on the page called by ajax and just use `$('#container').html(data)`.

This has gotten really long I really hope I've explained it clearly. But if you have further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks Kyokasuigetsu can you provide a bit more detail please on the receipt of data back from submit-ticket-ajax-1.php so I can understand how it is being captured?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Kyokasuigetsu - I think you may have mis-understood my requirement though.  I am not trying to pass variables to submit-ticket-ajax-1.php.  I am trying to send variables from submit-ticket-ajax-1.php back to submit-ticket.php so that they can be used in a form on submit-ticket.php. Example, user selects a user and the users assets appear with tick boxes (loaded from submit-ticket-ajax-1.php) the user ticks the computer affected.  That input  is currently captured on submit-ticket-ajax-1.php, I need to pass that input back to submit-ticket.php...

Comment: ... for use in the rest of the form without refreshing.  Many thanks also for your advice topics.  I will have a good read up on these.

Comment: but in your original code you're passing values to submit-ticket-ajax-1.php: xmlhttp.open("GET","./includes/submit-ticket-ajax-1.php?q="+str,true);

Comment: Yeah - that value is then used to perform additional database queries and provide further options to the user.  I need to pass their input on the additional options back to the original page so I can process them with the rest of the form data. Thanks Kyokasuigetsu

Comment: well your thank you is nice, but I'd really appreciate it if you could upvote or accept my answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: added an upvote as what you say is correct however I am not sure it is the answer to what I asked.  Either that or I am missing something.  I am trying to pass variables from submit-ticket-ajax-1.php back to submit-ticket.php for use in the form without reloading the page.  Can you advise on this requirement?  Your answer seems to explain how to pass variables from submit-ticket.php to submit-ticket-ajax-1.php.

Comment: thanks for the upvote, I guess I misunderstand. Let me try to explain it to you. See the updates section.

Comment: Fantastic update Kyokasuigetsu.  Really appreciate it!  I can't test it our today but is looking spot on!  As soon as I have given it a go I will come back and accept your answer.  I just wish I could upvote again!

Comment: Thanks Kyokasuigetsu - I think I'm almost there.  One question I have from googling and trying to get this working is that could you not retrieve the data within the GET rather than having 2 requests GET and POST? Also could you please provide a working example for outputting the data, say for email, but with a div id of test, I'm not sure if I'm assigning it correctly.  I have now simplified my ajax page and removed all HTML.  I am going to have to read up on jQuery a lot more!